# How to get child pages and loop through it's data on another page type?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `TestimonalHolder` page type that has `Testimonials` page type as its children which each have a `Message` $db field to store a testimonal.

Question is how do I access that `$Message` field on my `HomePage.ss` for example so I can loop through them and will put them into a slider etc.

**Testimonials.php**

```
class Testimonials extends Page {
    private static $db = array(
        'Message' => 'Text'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Testimonials', array(
            TextareaField::create('Message')
        ));

        return $fields;
    }
}

class Testimonials_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

I know I can loop through them by using this code on my `TestimonialHolder.ss` page:

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    $Message
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your HomePage.php

```
public function getTestimonials($limit = 5) {
    return Testimonials::get()->limit($limit);
}
```

Then in your template, just use `$Testimonials` like you would `$Children`.

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
<% loop $Testimonials('BlogPost').Limit(5) %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

With this `$List` helper you can access a simple datalist (even with `Filter()`, `Sort()` and `Limit()`) directly in your template, although this violates pure MVC a bit.

So handle with care!

See also: http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/retrieving-some-dataobjects-in-template-without-php-getter/ (disclaimer: my blog)